# How to monitor growth of On Premise Azure Devops Server

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We have our on-premise Azure DevOps Server that is growing quite fast. The database files (SQL Server 14) were about 130 GB. In less than a month are now 160 GB.
There's an agent monitor (maybe an Azure DevOps extension?) to log mostly Azure DevOps operations that may cause this? Not only push etc. standard GIT operation but something more specific? We have several repositories, pipelines, artifacts, etc.

Edit: auditing on Azure DevOps Services isn't available for on-premises deployments. And more there are several 3rd part providers offering this service but again seems like they work only in the cloud.
What eventually I'm looking for is a way to know the memory occupancy of a single Team Project or its pipeline/release etc. Then it will be easy to check day after day who is growing so rapidly.

Comment: Hello there, please check whether the answer below can help you and feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

- You can check the Azure DevOps server growth using continuous monitoring  by application insights
- You can set the alert rules using the below sample CLI script

> To modify alert rule settings:
> In the left pane of the release pipeline page, select **Configure Application Insights Alerts**.

```
$subscription = az account show --query "id";$subscription.Trim("`"");$resource="/subscriptions/$subscription/resourcegroups/"+"$(Parameters.AppInsightsResourceGroupName)"+"/providers/microsoft.insights/components/" + "$(Parameters.ApplicationInsightsResourceName)";
az monitor metrics alert create -n 'Availability_$(Release.DefinitionName)' -g $(Parameters.AppInsightsResourceGroupName) --scopes $resource --condition 'avg availabilityResults/availabilityPercentage < 99' --description "created from Azure DevOps";
az monitor metrics alert create -n 'FailedRequests_$(Release.DefinitionName)' -g $(Parameters.AppInsightsResourceGroupName) --scopes $resource --condition 'count requests/failed > 5' --description "created from Azure DevOps";
az monitor metrics alert create -n 'ServerResponseTime_$(Release.DefinitionName)' -g $(Parameters.AppInsightsResourceGroupName) --scopes $resource --condition 'avg requests/duration > 5' --description "created from Azure DevOps";
az monitor metrics alert create -n 'ServerExceptions_$(Release.DefinitionName)' -g $(Parameters.AppInsightsResourceGroupName) --scopes $resource --condition 'count exceptions/server > 5' --description "created from Azure DevOps";
```

- You can modify the script and add additional rules, and you can even modify alert conditions. or you can even remove alert rules which you don't require

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not exactly what I need.